# Selecting div in parent element

Tags: jquery, html

I keep running into this problem due to hilarious short term memory loss...

What I'm trying to do is `slideToggle` a div element which resides in the same parent element as the button.

There are multiple html constructs on each loaded page, so choosing the correct corresponding one is the goal.

```
<div class="exBtn">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/media/showTextButton.png">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="initialPostLoad">
    <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
</div> <!-- end initialPostLoad -->


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.exBtn a').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().closest('.initialPostLoad').slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().closest('.initialPostLoad').slideToggle();
```

You don't want `closest`. `closest` means "search among the parents of this element". You want to search among the siblings. In fact, what you want to do is to get the very next sibling. This is simple: just use `next`:

```
$(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
```

Comment: Ahhh I've been confused about parent, child and sibling. This, coming from someone who isn't an only child...

Answer (score 0):

Use `.next()`

```
$(this).parent().next('.initialPostLoad').slideToggle();
```

as `.initialPostLoad` is next to your `exBtn`